# How do I get regularly updated external data into Wagtail?

Tags: wagtail

I'm building an app that needs to know about entities outside of the CMS; files in a storage location, stuff in remote REST APIs, etc... Those things are changed by apps and services external to my Wagtail app.

Until now, my approach would have been to write to my CMS' API using some serverless gaffer-tape-and-string. However, as I understand it, I can't write to the Wagtail API. So how do I get remote data into Wagtail?

Thoughts so far are to create a page type for each of the above objects (in my case, for example, audio files, livestream episodes), and then from within Wagtail go and get that data, then use the "programatically create a page" process to add information about the entities. Is that the best approach?

If so, how do I go about triggering that? I'm aware of hooks (for UI events) and signals (to trigger events in other platforms), but they're both outbound. How can I configure Wagtail to do something on an inbound event/webhook, or even on a schedule? Unfortunately running the manage.py script with cron is out of the question because of the way this app will be hosted.

Answer (score 0):

```
var timezone = jstz.determine();
timezone.name();
```

"Europe/London"